# HTML5 - Increase size of edge of marker on canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, html5-canvas, draw

I have various draw functions that draw lines going up, down, right and left on a canvas. Whenever I draw, there is a 1x1 black marker that tracks where the last mark was made, and positions itself where the last point was drawn. I've tried making the marker bigger, but it messes up the marker by writing over the original blue lines in the functions. How can I make the black marker bigger (5x5) without messing up the original blue lines being drawn?

Comment: what do you mean, writing over the blue lines?

Comment: Instead of only being where the last spot blue was made was, the black overwrites all the blue lines. What I want is a bigger marker (5x5) that doesn't go over all the blue lines, but instead does what it did while it was 1x1 - positioning itself where the last mark was made.

Comment: Can you share code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @HughJ. without any code we can't really help you out, but I just create a very basic canvas with a few lines on it if that helps. jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bc6a2pzz/

Comment: An idea would be to stack 2 canvases on top of each other, one only for the mark and like, the other for the drawing (lines).